# Is there a way to use the CMakeTools extension for vs code with a cmake from a docker image?

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm recently looking into how to manage multiple toolchains on local workstations as well as a CI/CD system.
Looking into this I realised, that docker actually might give me all what I need.

My docker images contain cmake, the compile toolchain and additional tooling needed for verification. This principle works just fine when using cmake via CLI. Unfortunately I was not able to find anything on how to get the call to docker working with the nice cmake-tools GUI, that I got so used to. Currently I'm configuring and building with special vs code tasks that use `docker run --rm -v${workspaceFolder}:/usr/project cmake-docker cmake`.

Is there a way to do this?

I asked the development team of the extension before on github but they forwarded me to here.

Comment: you could try setting [cmake.cmakePath](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html#cmake-cmakepath) to `docker run ....`

Comment: yep, I tried this before and just now again and get this error message "Bad CMake executable " docker run --rm -v"c:\[...]\coding_projects\minimal_example:/usr/project" cmake-gcc-docker cmake". Is it installed or settings contain the correct path (cmake.cmakePath)?"

Comment: The authors of the cmakeTools extension pointed me towards the [remote-containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) visual studio code extension. Originally I wanted to keep my docker images as small as possible by just holding the neccessary build toolchain, but I guess the remote-container extension will workaround this problem by a small price (building parts of visual studio code and extensions directly into the docker image)

Comment: Could try putting the docker command in a bash script then setting that as cmakePath

Comment: well, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work neither... It fails with the same error message that I mentioned earlier...

Comment: @Moritz: Did you get this to work in any way or did remote-containers satisfy your needs?

Comment: Hi @Kristofer, I really haven't continued looking into this. I rather changed to CLion for development and am happy with the support they have :) ... Sorry not to be of more help.